# System.NullReferenceException using list of T in app.xaml.cs

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to store objects in a List of T to use the list with all my pages in my Windows Phone 8 app.

This is my List in App.xaml.cs:

```
  public partial class App : Application
    {
        public List<Worker> listWorkers { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides easy access to the root frame of the Phone Application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The root frame of the Phone Application.</returns>
        public static PhoneApplicationFrame RootFrame { get; private set; }
```

This is my code behind:

```
private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (App.Current as App).listWorkers.Add(new Worker { Name = "Test", Age = 15 });
        textBlockOutput.Text = (App.Current as App).listWorkers.Count.ToString();
    }
```

And this is my Worker class:

```
public class Worker
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The exception is: 
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's totally normal. Where are you initializing the listWorkers property? before you can use .Add method you need to create a new instance of the list, for example in the App.xaml.cs constructor:

`listWorkers = new List< Worker>();`

Answer (score 3):

From your code, it seems you have forgotten to initialize the list before using it:

```
listWorkers = new List<Worker>();
```

By the way, this kind of exception is very easy to see the cause in debugging mode.